# Confusing method overloading in Java

Tags: java

Following is the code relevant to **constructor overloading** in Java. Let's have a look at it.

```
package temp;

final public class Main
{
    private Main(Object o)
    {
        System.out.println("Object");
    }

    private Main(double[] da)
    {
        System.out.println("double array");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
    {
        Main main = new Main(null);
    }
}
```

---

In the above code, constructors are being overloaded in which one has a formal parameter of type Object and the other has the formal parameter of type double (array).

---

```
Main main = new Main(null);
```

One of the constructors is being invoked by the above statement which is using a **null** value as it's actual argument and the program is displaying the output **double array** on the console. How does the compiler resolve a specific constructor (or a method, if such is a case) dynamically at run time in such a situation?

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate; that question was about dynamic dispatch whereas there is no runtime type here, since `null` is being passed in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's resolved at *compile time* to `double[]`, because it's the [most specific](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.5) member to resolve to:

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, [...] The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.

Answer (score 2):

Java will call the most-specific constructor possible.

See *Class Instance Creation Expressions* ([JLS 15.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#41147)) and *Method Invocation Expressions* ([JLS 15.12](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#20448))

Answer (score -1):

Object is the superclass of all classes. Hence the most specific type that matches the arguments will be called and by this it is resolved at compile time.

Comment: What do you mean 'hence'? This is a *non sequitur*.